MAT CLI List_objects report export with depth level 2
I am using eclipse MAT tool to export a report from .hprof. In which i need list object report in text format. I am using a following xml for depth level one. I cannot get it to depth level 2, where all the important details are.
Here is the XML.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<report name="Custom Heap Dump Report">   
  <section name="heapzip">  
    <query name="%overview.threads">
        <param key="sort_column" value="#2" />
        <param key="limit" value="5" />
        <command>list_objects org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread</command>
    </query>
  </section>  
</report>

current output :
Class Name                                                                           | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread @ 0xca4f8278  http-nio-8060-exec-47        |          128 |   155,178,936
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread @ 0xca47aee8  http-nio-8060-exec-101       |          128 |   120,593,344
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread @ 0xca5a2538  http-nio-8060-exec-1         |          128 |    47,745,824
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread @ 0xca594e28  http-nio-8060-exec-97        |          128 |     1,496,048
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread @ 0xca5dcd80  http-nio-8060-exec-45        |          128 |     1,463,720
Total: 5 entries                                                                     |              |              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

what is need is information one level down as well as below screenshot.

